# Makefile with source command not working

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile

```
env:
    source venv/bin/activate
```

When I do `make env` to activate a python virtual env, I'm getting the following error

> source venv/bin/activate make: source: No such file or directory make:
> *** [env] Error 1

But when I copy `source venv/bin/activate` and run in the shell, it runs fine. Do I need to set the current dir inside the Makefile?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the error message with the `\`\`\`` … `\`\`\`` syntax,  showing the actual line break(s).

Comment: Also, please explain what you want to accomplish. Do you want to modify the state of the current shell; i.e.,  to use ``make env`` as an alias for ``source venv/bin/activate`` in your interactive shell? Or do you want to modify the state of your `make` program, so you can use commands from the Python virtual environment in your  `Makefile`?

Comment: Loosely related (maybe): [Why can’t I load modules while executing my bash script, but only when sourcing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194893/23408) (on Unix & Linux), where I am the author of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is a *shell built-in* command, not an executable that you can start from anywhere but a shell. What `source` does is to read and execute the contents of a file **in the current shell, *without starting a new shell***.

The purpose of that is to modify the state of the current shell (if you just `sh venv/bin/activate`, your shell would also execute the contents of the `activate` script, but then be done, and quit).

But what you want to do is *modify the state of your `make` program*. Running the `activate` script in a shell that you spawn, in whatever way, from `make`, is not going to change anything about the environment that `make` sees.
That's because every program (A) launched by another program (B) gets its own copy of the environment of the launching program (B), which it (A) can change to its heart's desire, without affecting the environment of the launching program (B).

So, what you want to do cannot work, even theoretically.

If you need to run some Makefile inside a venv, you will have to source the `activate` script first, and from the thus modified shell then start `make`; not the other way around.

Comment: Your facts are correct, but I question your interpretation of the OP’s intent.  I guess that they want to be able to use `make env` as an alias for ``source venv/bin/activate`` in their interactive shell.  Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні but then my answer would still stand 100 %  – you cannot use make to change the state of the shell that called make.